# Accessing Attribute Table (in composer) with PyQgis

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a QGIS (3.44) project containing a composer. In this composer i inserted an attribute table (which i've given the **item_id** 'tab').

I would like to be able to access this attribute table properties using PyQgis.
I'm using the following code so far :

```
projectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = projectInstance.layoutManager()
at=projectLayoutManager.layouts()[0].itemById('tab')
```

The last line returns a **QgsLayoutFrame** which is a bit misleading for me ...

How can i 'browse' the content of this **QgsLayoutFrame** to reach my attribute table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need acces to `QgsLayoutMultiFrame` object.

**Example code with some extras**

```
# Table Sample
tabla = layout.itemById('tabla')
tabla_item = tabla.multiFrame ()      
tabla_item.setVectorLayer(<my_layer>)
tabla_item.setDisplayedFields(["column_0","column_1"])

column_0 = tabla_item.columns()[0]
# Change heading name column 0
column_0.setHeading("New name 0")

column_1 = tabla_item.columns()[1]
# Change heading name column 1
column_1.setHeading("New name 1")
# Change order column 0
column_0.setSortOrder(Qt.AscendingOrder)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I was completely unable to find that in the API doc. ... Hard to understand the 'meaning' of some classes ... or did u use any other ressource to find that ?

Comment: Your welcome ! Nope, I just use the API documentation